# Remove all occurrences of text between brackets including themselves

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need remove all occurrences of text between brackets including themselves of lines.

I use a piece of code that was worth, until it appears more than one element

```
$array[] = '[2016-12-26 16:48:57 +0100] pkgacct working dir : /cprsync_back3/tamainut';
$array[] = '[2016-12-26 16:48:57 +0100] Copying SSL certificates, CSRs, and keys...[2016-12-26 16:48:57 +0100] Done'

foreach ($array as &$line) {
    $line = preg_replace("/\[[^)]+\]/","",$line);
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This works well with the first line, but not with the second line

```
pkgacct working dir : /cprsync_back3/tamainut
Done
```

What need for extract only **[..] but conserving this [..]** ?

Comment: Conserve when there is a match in the string? Maybe `^(\[([^)]+?)\]).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^\[[^)]+?\].*$`?

Comment: Btw [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) *subject* can also be an array [like in this demo](https://eval.in/704883).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the loop; also your regex needs a fix (note I've added `?` quantifier).

```
$array[
    '[2016-12-26 16:48:57 +0100] pkgacct working dir : /cprsync_back3/tamainut',
    '[2016-12-26 16:48:57 +0100] Copying SSL certificates, CSRs, and keys...[2016-12-26 16:48:57 +0100] Done'
];

foreach ($array as $key => $line) {
    $array[$key] = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/', "", $line);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Answers should have explanations. This doesn't make sense because you are just echoing the original line..

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
\[[^][]*(?(?=\[)(?R))[^][]*\]
```

[Live demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/sTlH1A/2)

Explanation:

```
\[              # Match opening bracket
[^][]*          # Match anything but `[` & `]` characters
(?(?=\[)(?R))   # If previous match ends before `[` repeat whole pattern
[^][]*          # //
\]              # Match closing bracket
```

This regex is supposed to work on ***nested brackets*** as well.

Code snippet:

```
preg_replace("@\[[^][]*(?(?=\[)(?R))[^][]*\]@", "", $line);
```

Comment: supposed to work [but doesn't it seems](https://www.regex101.com/r/HYZUVI/1) how about [like this](https://www.regex101.com/r/HYZUVI/2).

Comment: Good point. It doesn't match anything between `]...[` inside brackets since there is no quantifier involved.  Saying that I have to apply it [**`\[[^][]*+(?:(?R)?[^][]*)*+]`**](https://www.regex101.com/r/sTlH1A/3) (also shortened *conditional statement* of recursion to a `?` quantifier). This is a linear regex which you can compare to your proposed one. @bobblebubble

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the parenthesis by a bracket in the character class:

```
$line = preg_replace("/\[[^\]]+\]/","",$line);
//                   here __^
```